# Set default Locale in Java

Tags: java, locale

My problem is simple: i should change the default Locale in a batch java(Procedure java, with main method), without affecting other batch (always java) that run on the same server, and at the same time. It is possible to do this?
thanks in advance for replies

Comment: Unless they run in the same JVM, setting [`Locale.setDefault`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#setDefault%28java.util.Locale.Category,%20java.util.Locale%29) should not affect the other programs. With "the same server", do you mean the same physical machine, or like the same Tomcat instance or whatever?

Comment: How are you proposing to change the default locale?